# Mi estilo no cambia al hacer click

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy creando una página con utilidades (están programadas en un archivo JavaScript diferente) en el cual tengo botones que se deben activar y desactivar. Para eso requiero el cambiar los estilos y el variable que retiene si el botón está activo o no. El problema es que al hacer click, los estilos **no cambian** como se lo pido a JavaScript. El código de mi evento **click** se corta a mitad del camino y nada que cambia mi estilo. He intentado de todo lo que está a mi disposición pero nada. ¿Alguien me puede decir qué pasa? Gracias.

```js
var includePasswordNumbers = "false";
var includePasswordSymbols = "false";
var onColor = "green";
var onColorShadow = "0px 0px 24px green";
var offColor = "red";
var offColorShadow = "0px 0px 15 red";

var includePasswordNumbers = "false";
var includePasswordSymbols = "false";
var onColor = "green";
var onColorShadow = "0px 0px 24px green";
var offColor = "red";
var offColorShadow = "0px 0px 15 red";
/*-------------FUNCIONES---------------*/


/*--------------BOTONES----------------*/
var resultEvadeArea = document.getElementById("resultEvadeArea");

var evadetext = document.getElementById("evadetext");

const processEvasingText = document.getElementById("processEvasingText");
processEvasingText.addEventListener("click", function(processEvasingText) {
    var inputText = evadetext.value;
    if (!inputText) {
        resultEvadeArea.innerHTML = message("msg2");
    } else {
    resultEvadeArea.innerHTML = tmntools.evadeRulesText(inputText);
    }
});


//De reVersa mami B)
var resultReverseArea = document.getElementById("resultReverseArea");

var reversetext = document.getElementById("reversetext");

const processReversingText = document.getElementById("processReversingText");
processReversingText.addEventListener("click", function (processReversingText) {
    var inputText = reversetext.value;
    if (!inputText) {
        resultReverseArea.innerHTML = message("msg1");
    } else {
        resultReverseArea.innerHTML = tmntools.reverseText(inputText);
    }
});

// Muy segura que ha de ser la contra xdxd

var resultPasswordArea = document.getElementById("resultPasswordArea");

const generatePassword = document.getElementById("generatePassword");
generatePassword.addEventListener("click", function(generatePassword) {
    resultPasswordArea.innerHTML = "Todo bien.";
});

//Aquí es donde tengo problemas
var passwordNumbers = document.getElementById("passwordNumbers");
passwordNumbers.addEventListener("click", function (passwordNumbers) {
    if (includePasswordNumbers == "false") {
        includePasswordNumbers = "true";
        passwordNumbers.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        passwordNumbers.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 24px green";
    } else {
        includePasswordNumbers == "true";
        passwordNumbers.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        passwordNumbers.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 15 red";
    }
    resultPasswordArea.innerHTML = "El botón escucha clicks";
});
```

```css
/* Listas */
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

ul > li {
    background-color: #242430;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Listas para botones */
.buttons {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.buttons li {
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons li .button {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons li .onoffbutton {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tool_list">
    <li>Evadir reglas de la comunidad:<div class="subspaces"><input id="evadetext">
    <div class="button" id="processEvasingText">Procesar</div>
    <br>
    <p id="resultEvadeArea">Aquí aparecerán los resultados. Nota: si las letras presentan errores, intenta volver a procesar.</p>
    </div></li>
        
    <li>Invertir texto: <div class="subspaces"><input id="reversetext">
    <div class="button" id="processReversingText">Procesar</div>
    <br>
    <p id="resultReverseArea">Aquí aparecerán los resultados.</p>
    </div></li>
        
    <li>Generar contraseña: <div class="subspaces">
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li><div class="onoffbutton" id="passwordNumbers">Números</div></li>
        <li><div class="onoffbutton"  id="passwordSymbols">Símbolos</div></li>
        <li><div class="button" id="generatePassword">Generar</div></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p id="resultPasswordArea">Aquí aparecerán los resultados.</p>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

> **P.D.:** Las funciones que están antes de que me den problemas sí están programadas en otro archivo.
>
> **P.D.2:** Mi botón escucha los clicks pero su estilo es el que no cambia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando trabajes con `addEventListener` directamente a un elemento, puedes acceder a ese elemento dentro de la función utilizando `this`, entonces como es el mismo elemento al que le quieres cambiar el estilo entonces utilizas `this` para cambiar sus propiedades.

```js
var includePasswordNumbers = true; // Auxiliar para que entre al if

//Aquí es donde tengo problemas
var passwordNumbers = document.getElementById("passwordNumbers");
passwordNumbers.addEventListener("click", function (passwordNumbers) {
    if (includePasswordNumbers == "false") {
        includePasswordNumbers = "true";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        this.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 24px green";
    } else {
        includePasswordNumbers == "true";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        this.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 15 red";
    }
    resultPasswordArea.innerHTML = "El botón escucha clicks";
});
```

```css
/* Listas */
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

ul > li {
    background-color: #242430;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Listas para botones */
.buttons {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.buttons li {
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons li .button {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons li .onoffbutton {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tool_list">   
    <li>Generar contraseña: <div class="subspaces">
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li><div class="onoffbutton" id="passwordNumbers">Números</div></li>
        <li><div class="onoffbutton"  id="passwordSymbols">Símbolos</div></li>
        <li><div class="button" id="generatePassword">Generar</div></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p id="resultPasswordArea">Aquí aparecerán los resultados.</p>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Por favor, explica como y porqué esta respuesta soluciona el problema para que así todos los usuarios puedan comprender y aprender con ella. Gracias.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ya voy a poder solucionar el problema y recortar el tiempo de carga, aunque no entiendo del todo la respuesta. ¡Ten un buen día!

Comment: Al final no cambié el valor inicial de los booleanos del principio porque no va acorde al funcionamiento de mi programa. Lo demás funciona bien.